# provide variable as arguments in shell script

Tags: shell

My script test.sh contains

```
for i in {2,51,52,53,54}; do
    curl -v -X PUT http://localhost:8080/v3/progress/$i/?status=Open
done
```

I would like to test.sh and provide the list as argument

how can I do it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Can you be a little more specific about what you want to achieve?  Do you want to specify the list of numbers as arguments to the script?  That could be done by simply saying `for i; do curl ...; done`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ -n "$1" ] ; do
    curl -v -X PUT http://localhost:8080/v3/progress/$1/?status=Open
    shift
done
```

Run it as ./test.sh 2 51 52 53 54

Comment: A `for` loop is much simpler: `for arg; do curl ... "http://.../$arg/?status=Open"; done`.